# How to prevent BlueStacks from starting automtically?

Tags: osx-lion, bluestacks

I installed BlueStacks How can I prevent it from starting automatically?

Comment: @chit0x reported. The question was about macos but your "answer" is for windows - totally useless

Answer (score 7):

To prevent BlueStacks from autostart you need to remove the **uHD-Agent** from the Login Items list:

`System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items`

Click on the row **uHD-Agent** (not the checkbox) and then click the remove (`-`) button under list.

Comment: No, it's not listed in `Login Items`.